# Small and large double values in C++: which are more precise?

Tags: c++, double

I use a coefficient for comparison (as a map key) that is always greater than 1, often significantly greater. Is it more precise to use a reverse version (1 / coeff)? The coefficient defines some scale and is obtained by dividing one double number by another, so this can be easily performed in 2 different ways.

In program design there is no big difference, but I've read somewhere that the implementation of double numbers increases the "comparison precision" of less-than-one double values over others (like 0 < x < 1 numbers have more "dense" packing on the axis).

---

Somewhat related question concerning non-uniform number density:
[How many bits of precision for a double between -1.0 and 1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959902/how-many-bits-of-precision-for-a-double-between-1-0-and-1-0)

Comment: See http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your numbers are NOT integers, then it won't improve or worsen the actual "exactness" of the number to do 1/x - it will get worse because you are doing another math operation. So I would avoid it for that reason alone.

All floating point numbers have a limited number of bits to express the mantissa. There isn't any difference in "how precise" the value is whether it is 1/x or x. In binary form of floating point numbers, just like in decimal form we can't express 1/3 as a decimal number (there's not an infinite supply of 3's), so 0.1 becomes 0.0999999999999999999999999....  if you try to express it in binary form. It doesn't really matter if the number is 10.1, 8.1 or 100001.1, as well as 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9 [and any other number that contains that]. On the other hand 0.5, 0.25, 0.125 are perfectly "nice" in binary.

You really can't make a floating point value "better" by doing math on it. It can only get "worse" (but it's really (1/2<sup>52</sup>) worse, so probably not really critical for most cases).

To clarify:

Let's say we have the value 100 (accurately represented in floating point, as it is an integer, and all integer less than the 2<sup>mantissa_bits</sup> are stored with full precision and no error). 1/100 is 0.01. If we do the "decimal to binary" on this:
First multiply by 2 until we get a number >= 1:

```
0.01 * 2 = 0.02 
0.02 * 2 = 0.04
0.04 * 2 = 0.08
0.08 * 2 = 0.16
0.16 * 2 = 0.32  // We're getting there 
0.32 * 2 = 0.64
0.64 * 2 = 1.28  // Exponent = -(steps we needed) to get here = -7
                 // Mantissa (M) so far = 1
```

Now we have one bit. Subtract one and repeat the multiply by 2

0.28 * 2 = 0.56   // M=1.0
   0.56 * 2 = 1.12   // M=1.01 - subtract 1
   0.12 * 2 = 0.24   // M=1.010
   0.24 * 2 = 0.48   // M=1.0100
   0.48 * 2 = 0.96   // M=1.01000
   0.96 * 2 = 1.92   // M=1.010000
   0.92 * 2 = 1.84   // M=1.0100001
   0.84 * 2 = 1.76   // M=1.01000011
   0.76 * 2 = 1.52   // M=1.010000111
   0.52 * 2 = 1.04   // M=1.0100001111
   0.04 * 2 = 0.08   // M=1.01000011110
   0.08 * 2 = 0.16   // M=1.010000111100

Remember that we've seen the 0.04, 0.08 numbers before - this will continue forever.

So, we started out with an accurate number, that became inaccurate. If you start out with an inaccurate number, you won't ever get an accurate one (The floating point part of the processor it doesn't realize that 0.00999999999999999999999999999999999999999 is actually 0.01 - even if it rounds up/down the actual result).

Edit2: Add/Subtract of large + small number.

Now, adding a very small number to a large number, that's a different matter. It all depends on the exact range of the numbers involved. When doing addition or subtractin, the numbers are normalised (just like you'd do if you did the same thing on paper). So we get:

```
500000 + 0.000000025

 500000.000000000
+     0.000000025
 ----------------
 500000.000000025
```

Now, the problem comes if the small number doesn't fit after we multiply by 2 until they have the same exponent. In this case 0.000000025 is around 2<sup>-25</sup>, and 500000 is ~ 2<sup>19</sup> - 19 + 25 = 44, so within the range of 53 bits, but the 0.000000025 value may be slightly rounded off [I haven't done the conversion to see if it is a "precise" or "not precise" floating point number].

In other words, in this case, it works. It will have a VERY small impact on the overall value, of course, but I expect that is the intention, or you'd have used a larger number to add with.

Comment: Imagin I don't have to do math. Imagin I'm in a 3 Dimensional room and want to calculate my movement in flaoting point numbers. And I have to decide Whats my origin? 0/0/0 So I'm handling much with close numbers to 0. Or 500000/500000/500000 Where I get flaoting point numbers close to 500000. It wouldn't change anything in precsission? Did I get that right?

Comment: If your numbers are around 500000 or 1/500000 won't make much of a difference to how precisely the value can be represented. And doing a 1/x will just make the value the same or slightly worse, so you won't gain anything from that. You may gain in OTHER ways (e.g. you need to divide several times by that number, and because of that, end up gaining by turning `value/x` into `value * one_over_x` - but that's a speed of execution thing, not accuracy in representing the number.

Comment: Sorry, my `/` sign was missleading. Im not doing calculations on that 500000. I was talking about x/y/z Coordinates. I just want to know: would doing chains of calculations on 0 result in the same precission as doing them on 500000. For example In a 3D game. I have event handler and say: `while (w_key_down){Origin = Origin + 0.000000025}` Would it make a difference the Origin starts with 0 or 500000? Or would the precsission be in both cases equal? (I'm also clear of it that it is stupid to take the 500000 in aspects of runtime performance.  But I'm just asking about precsission.)

Comment: In that program the key is obtained by dividing one double number by another (I clarified the question).

Comment: So, basically, you have the choice of x/y or y/x? I expect you have to pick numbers for x and y very carefully to make any notable difference in which is "more accurate".

Comment: Yes, both options are valid. 
*** I found a question with the mention of a non-uniform number density: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959902/how-many-bits-of-precision-for-a-double-between-1-0-and-1-0

Comment: And regarding to my Question, Did I get your edit right, That as Higher the value the greater the loss of precission? (Doesn't matter how small the precission loss is?)

Comment: If the number density around zero is greater then there can be more "distinguishable" double values in that area, but how significant is the difference? Depending on it there can be also practical interest in addition to theoretical knowledge.

Comment: The "loss of precision" when subtracting or adding will be larger in absolute terms (make the number really large, and adding millions won't make it change), but the proportional error is always around 1/2^52 of the actual value, because that's how large the mantissa is (assuming 64-bit IEEE-754 representation).

Answer (score 0):

For keeping key-value pair in a map, I would suggest to have fixed precision of n digits after decimal (rounded upto n digits after decimal) and then have either string or integer (multiplying the double value with 10^n and taking the integral part) as key in order to avoid confusion and surprises. In floating point arithmetic, 1.00000000001 and 0.9999999999999 are all same but as key they are not same

Comment: The question was (As far I got it right) Are floating point values of double precsission more precise if they are close to 0 or would the precission be the same on every Integer number represented by double precsission floating point type (note I'm talking about Intege numbers not talking about integer type)

Comment: Yes, double precision is more precise than single precision, as the name says so. A floating point number is represented as mantissa and exponent form, more the precision, more digits you have in mantisa

Comment: That was my or his question neither. I didn't even drop a word of single precision. What I want to know. and OP probably aswell: Imagin we have a 1Byte floating point type. we say the range ist from -25 to 25. So the question is: Would we have on each number the posibilty of repreasenting x.2 x.4 x.6 x.8 and x.0? Or would we have 0.01 0.06 0.11 0.12 0.16 and like 10 more values close to 0 And there for at 24 only the represantation of 24.3 ?